# Use UIControl Component in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui, uicontrol

I'm first in SwiftUI and IOS. I want to use [SimpleCheckBox](https://github.com/BeauNouvelle/SimpleCheckbox) in my SwiftUI.

But I only get

```
Error:(14, 18) static method 'buildBlock' requires that 'Checkbox' conform to 'View'
```

This is my code.

```swift
var body: some View {
  HStack {
    Checkbox(frame: CGRect(x: 50, y: 50, width: 25, height: 25))
    Text("HelloWorld!")

  }
}
```

How can I use UIControl in SwiftUI?

Comment: You will need to wrap `Checkbox` in a [`UIViewRepresentable`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/uiviewrepresentable) - See https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/interfacing-with-uikit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Writting a custom CheckBox in SwiftUI is not a lot of work. This is a working minimum version:

```
struct CheckBox: View {

    @Binding var isSelected: Bool

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: { self.isSelected.toggle() }) {
            Image(systemName: self.isSelected ? "checkmark.circle" : "circle")
        }
    }
}
```